# Plotting data set with extra points using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have searched stackoverflow to find an answer to my issue, but to no avail.  I wish to plot an earthquake data set with a yellow star to represent the center of my study area.  However, I can only plot the earthquake data and cannot plot the star.  I have tried two solutions:  just plotting both data sets such as what I have in my code, or using a subplot. 
 In other words, what is the equivalent of MatLab's `hold on` command in Python/matplotlib?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read in latitudes and longitudes
eq_data = open('eq_data')
lats, lons = [], []
mag = []
for index, line in enumerate(eq_data.readlines()):
    if index > 0:
        lats.append(float(line.split(',')[0]))
        lons.append(float(line.split(',')[1]))
        mag.append(float(line.split(',')[2]))

#Build the basemap
antmap = Basemap(projection='spstere', boundinglat=10, lon_0=-60, resolution='f')
antmap.drawcoastlines(color='black', linewidth=0.15)
antmap.fillcontinents(color='0.95')
antmap.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
x,y = antmap(lons, lats)
x1,x2= (0,-90)
antmap.plot(x1,x2, 'r*', markersize=10)
antmap.plot(x,y,'ro', markersize=8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know what `hold on` does but in your code, fourth last line, you should have `x1,x2=antmap(0,-90)`

Comment: Is it possible that the earthquake data is covering the star? Try plotting the start second and see if it shows up.

Comment: Try [`antmap.plot(x1,x2, 'r*', markersize=10,zorder=10)`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) - the `zorder` changes the order in which your objects are drawn. The higher the number the more *on top* they are.